# How do I cache RSS feeds in order not to miss entries on client side?

Tags: rss

I'm using a client side RSS reader and turn on my PC at night. But some RSS feeds publish only a limited number of entries and old entries are removed from the feed. So sometimes I can miss entries.

In order to avoid that, I want to cache feeds on some web service. Is there something like it? Although I know server side readers like Google Reader solve this problem, I still like client side readers.

Answer (score 1):

[FeedDemon](http://www.newsgator.com/individuals/feeddemon/) can sync with Google Reader.